# If a matrix $A$ provides an orthonormal basis, do $AA^T$ and $A^TA$ yield different sized identity matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am used to the definition of an orthonormal basis as a collection of vectors. For example, if $e_1,...,e_k$ is an orthonormal basis for $W$, then 
$$e_i\cdot e_j = \delta_{ij} \forall i,j$$

But suppose $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times p}$ is an orthonormal basis for a vector space $V$, with $\dim (V) = n$.

Wouldn't that imply

$$\mathbf{AA^T} = \mathbf{I}_n$$ 
$$\mathbf{A^TA} = \mathbf{I}_p$$

I'm confused why this happens because that means $\mathbf{A^TA}$ wouldn't have the same dimensions as $V$. So how can it be a basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what it means for a matrix to "provide" or to "be" an orthonormal basis. It  might mean the rows are orthonormal or it might mean the columns  are orthonormal. The two are different if $A$ is not square - in that case if the rows are orthonormal the columns *cannot* be orthonormal, since the row space and column space have the same dimension.

Your idea that $A^TA$ and $AA^T$ are both identity matrices seems to indicate you think the rows are orthonormal and so are the columns; since that's impossible the problem goes away.

**Moral:** Don't make up terminology, at least not without providing a definition. The problem here, it seems to me, was fuzziness over the notion of a matrix "providing" or "being" an orthonormal basis. It doesn't say anything about either of those in the book.

**Note.** If $A$ is square then yes, the rows are orthonormal if and only if the colummns are. But this is not obvious or trivial...

Comment: The latter *is* trivial when you know that $AB = I$ implies $B = A^{-1}$ for square matrices.

Comment: @amsmath Yes of course it is. I can't imagine what your point is here - surely you're not claiming it's  trivial that a one-sided inverse must be an inverse.

Comment: No, I don't. Cause that follows from col rank equals row rank (which is not trivial).

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you mean that the columns of $A$ form an ONB of $V$. Then the answer is yes: The requirement on $A$ implies $p\le n$ and $\dim V = n$ implies $p\ge n$. So $p=n$ and $A$ is orthogonal.

Comment: You fixed the problem while I was typing a comment explaining that I objected to "The requirement on $A$", as though the hypotheses in the OP were clear, in spite of the undefined terms. Here you're explicit about what you're assuming, and you admit you're just guessing that that's what the OP meant.